# Weird behavior in dplyr slice for R

Tags: r, dplyr

When calling `slice(df, i)` in the dplyr package for R, if the row index I ask for doesn't exist (`nrows < i`), it appears to return all the rows but the first of the group, like I had called `slice(df, -1)`.

For example:

```
library(dplyr)

c1 <- c("a","b","c")
c2 <- 1:3
df <- data.frame(c1,c2)

slice(df,2)
```

The result will be as expected:

```
b  2
```

But if I call

```
slice(df, 5)
```

the result is every row *but* the first row:

```
b  2
c  3
```

This is especially irksome when using `group_by()` and THEN calling `slice()` on the groups. Is there a logical reason why `slice()` is doing this?

It seems like returning row(s) filled with NAs for row indices larger than 'nrows' in groups not "tall enough" to produce the requested slice could be a useful result.

This came up as I was trying to extract a ranked result from each group, but some groups did not have enough data while others did. e.g. "List the 10th highest sales-producing salesperson from each region." But in one of the regions there are only 8 salespersons.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example to your post.

Comment: More info on how to give a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: A similar problem applies to `slice(df,0)`, which should return an "empty" data.frame, as `df[0,]` does.

Comment: Ooh, and try `slice(df,NA_integer_)` to crash R.

Comment: Could someone please file these as bugs?

Answer (score 3):

I'm kinda late to this party but here goes.  There is a really simple solution to the error message "Error: incompatible types, expecting a character vector"

just insert `ungroup()` prior to your `mutate()` function and you should be OK.

But I think its a bug of some type in `slice()`. I will file a bug report.

Comment: Was this bug ever reported? if so, can you link it? It's more than 3 years later and the problem seems to persist...

Answer (score 0):

I agree: This behavior doesn't seem right. You can use the following as an alternative:

```
df <- data_frame(c1=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), c2=c(1,2,3,4))

#   c1 c2
# 1  a  1
# 2  a  2
# 3  b  3
# 4  c  4

# get the second smallest row for each group, or the last row for 
# groups with less than 2 elements
df %>% 
    group_by(c1) %>% 
    filter(row_number() == min(2, n()))
#   c1 c2
# 1  a  2
# 2  b  3
# 3  c  4
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I like it--go back to `filter` and recreate what `slice` is supposed to do with a touch of ingenuity!