# R use diff() for groups of rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, diff

Here is a simple example:

```
> df <- data.frame(sn=rep(c("a","b"), 3), t=c(10,10,20,20,25,25), r=c(7,8,10,15,11,17))
> df
  sn  t  r
1  a 10  7
2  b 10  8
3  a 20 10
4  b 20 15
5  a 25 11
6  b 25 17
```

Expected result is

```
 sn  t r
1  a 20 3
2  a 25 1
3  b 20 7
4  b 25 2
```

I want to group by a specific column ("sn"), leave some columns unchanged ("t" for this example), and apply diff() to remaining columns ("r" for this example).
I explored "dplyr" package to try something like:

```
df1 %>% group_by(sn) %>% do( ... diff(r)...)
```

but couldn't figure out correct code. 
Can anyone recommend me a clean way to get expected result?

Comment: Hi @dmitriy873 if any of the answers solves your pb you might click on "accept it" so that other people know that it was solved. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this (I don't use directly `diff` because it returns `n-1` values):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(sn) %>% group_by(sn) %>% mutate(r = r-lag(r)) %>% slice(2:n())
####       sn     t     r
####   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
#### 1      a    20     3
#### 2      a    25     1
#### 3      b    20     7
#### 4      b    25     2
```

The `slice` fonction is here to remove the NA rows created by the differenciation at the beginning of each group. One could also use `na.omit` instead, but it could also remove other lines unintentionally

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Using slice() on dataframe seems to be leading to some problems:df1 <- df %>% arrange(sn) %>% group_by(sn) %>% mutate(r = r-lag(r)) %>% slice(2:n()). Then: df1 %>% mutate(r = ifelse(r < 3, NA, r)) has - Error: corrupt 'grouped_df', contains 4 rows, and 6 rows in groups. However, df1$r[df1$r < 3] <- NA does work as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, i'm not aware of this. Another way is to use `na.omit` as suggested in my post and by akrun, or to replace the slice call by `filter(row_number()>1)` which does the same.

Comment: @dmitriy873 I don't get the error you mention. I have a quite recent version of R (3.2.3) and `dplyr` (dplyr_0.5.0), maybe that's the difference. I also saw this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491740/weird-behavior-in-dplyr-slice-for-r that dates back to 2015

Comment: It makes sense. My R is 3.2.2 and dplyr is 0.4.3. I will update R. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), set the `key` as 'sn' (it will order it based on 'sn'), grouped by 'sn', get the difference of 'r' with the `lag` of 'r' (i.e. `shift` in `data.table` does that) and remove the NA rows with `na.rows.

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df, key = "sn")[,  r := r-shift(r) , sn])
#   sn  t r
#1:  a 20 3
#2:  a 25 1
#3:  b 20 7 
#4:  b 25 2
```

---

Or if we are using `diff`, then make sure that length are the same as the `diff` output will be one less than the length of the original vector.  So, we can pad with NA and later remove by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   arrange(sn) %>%
   group_by(sn) %>%
   mutate(r = c(NA, diff(r))) %>%
   filter(!is.na(r))
#      sn     t     r 
#    <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1      a    20     3
#2      a    25     1
#3      b    20     7
#4      b    25     2
```

Comment: Thanks! Both methods work well. Right now, my data is not big (~50,000) but it is growing fast. In your opinion, which method will perform better on large data sets?

Comment: @dmitriy873  Both are good, but the data.table should be faster.